# Retrieving data from context and use it on doOnNext() from Spring Webflux

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a correlation ID stored in context (by using ***contextWrite***) and I'd like to recover and use it in the ***doOnNext()***, in which I implement some logging from previous data transformations.

Here's an example of what I achieved till now:

```
Mono.just("message")
   ...
   .doOnNext(it -> Mono.deferContextual(ctx -> Mono.just(ctx)
      .doOnNext(c -> log.info("correlation-id: "+ c.get(CORRELATION_ID)))))
   .subscribe();
```

Is this the only way to achieve what I want? It seems a little odd to me somehow. I'm still learning and I've been reading the context section from the Reactor doc, but I couldn't find anything that approximates what I'm trying to achieve.

**UPDATE 1**

I managed to achieve something like that (and didn't have to ***Mono.just()*** 2x):

```
Mono.deferContextual(ctx ->
   Mono.just("message")
      ...
      .doOnNext(it -> log.info("correlation-id: " + ctx.get(CORRELATION_ID)))
);
```

Still don't know if that is a best practice, but looks way better than the previous one

**UPDATE 2**

Reading and digging a little deeper into the code and documentation, I discovered that ***Mono.deferContextual()*** returns a Mono (my mistake for not noticing that before).As a result, for the first scenario, ***flatMap()*** should be used instead of ***doOnNext()***. To simulate the ***doOnNext()*** function, I'll have to refactor a little more to return the same received object on ***flatMap()***.

**UPDATE 3**

I think that I got to the final code with ***transformDeferredContextual()***. According to the reactor documentation:

> to access the context from the middle of an operator chain, use transformDeferredContextual(BiFunction)

Applying to my scenario:

```
Mono.just("message")
   ...
   .transformDeferredContextual((originalMono, context) -> {
         log.info("correlation-id: " + context.get(CORRELATION_ID)))
         
         return originalMono;
   })
   .subscribe();
);
```

It seems a bit odd, but till now, this seems like the best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something similar but prettier than your final approach:

```java
Mono.just("message")
   ...
    .transformDeferredContextual((originalMono, context) -> originalMono.doOnNext(e -> {
           log.info("correlation-id: " + context.get(CORRELATION_ID));
   }))
```

Comment: Marked yours as a solution because, in addition to being prettier, it allows me to make some transformations using originalMono, if needed. Thank you for sharing this approach!